# Phrase and symbol for "geometric absolute value"$ e^{|\ln(x)|}?$

Tags: terminology, logarithms, absolute-value

I'm calculate the median fractional difference between two vectors (to characterise the error in a quantity with a high dynamic range).  If $a/b = 0.1$, the fractional difference is $10$, and if $a/b = 10$, the fractional difference is also 10.  My quantity, which is only defined if $x>0$, is defined as

$$
\begin{cases} x, & \mbox{if } x \ge 1 \\ \frac{1}{x}, & \mbox{if } x < 1\end{cases}
$$

which is equal to (as $x>0$),

$$
e^{|\ln(x)|}.
$$

Do mathematicians have a usual word and symbol for this quantity?

Comment: I have been curious about this quantity as well

Comment: Are you looking for x if $|x| >= 1$ and $1/x$ if $|x| <= 1$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Right.  I didn't think of that because in my practical application, I already know that $x > 0$.  The issue becomes more involved if $x$ can be negative, because what is the fractional error if $a/b$ is negative?

Comment: I don't know this of the top of my head, but I would look for this in the theory of continued fractions and around the name of Gauss.